# Route [verification.resend] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to send emails from a Laravel application but Laravel is complaining and throwing the error exception

> "message": "Route [verification.resend] not defined. (View: C:\Users\Elomena\Projects\Clients\Pramopro\resources\views\auth\verify.blade.php)",
>       "exception": "ErrorException",

Following the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#verification-routing I have set up my `web.php` file like this

```
Auth::routes(['verfiy' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

But I can't find any route of these routes in the route list

```
email/resend 

email/verify 

email/verify/{id}
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: You have `verify` misspelled. But I don't see `verification.resend` defined anywhere in your routes.

Comment: Fixed the typo and getting a `Swift_TransportException` message `Authentication required`

Comment: That means you're not authenticated with your SMTP provider, so you'll have to put in the authentication settings in `config/mail.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @aynber I wasn't being authenticated successfully by SMTP provider. That was because after setting up the mailing config in env the configuration were yet to be cached so running `php artisan config:cache`fixed it.